# PrestaShop 1.6: manufacturer_name error

Tags: web-services, product, prestashop-1.6

I use PrestaShop 1.6.13. I user the Web Service of product which have id set 10 (http://myserver/api/products/10). When I update the attribute width, it displays an error:
[image]

Can you help me ??

Comment: share your code. but like the error mentions, you should remove the manufacturer_name from the request and try again.

Comment: I download the PSWebServiceLibrary.php file (URL: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php). After that, I create a file PHp named product.php and I insert this code:

define('DEBUG', true);
ini_set('display_errors','on');
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://myserver/');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'key');
require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);

Comment: $xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'api/products?schema=synopsis'));

$opt = array('resource' => 'products');
$opt['id'] = 8;
$xml = $webService->get($opt);

$resources = $xml->children()->children();

(continue)
$resources->quantity = 100;

$opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->edit($opt);

Answer (score 0):

I download the PSWebServiceLibrary.php file (URL: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php). After that, I create a file PHp named product.php and I insert this code:

```
define('DEBUG', true); 
ini_set('display_errors','on'); 
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://myserver/'); 
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'key'); 
require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php'); 
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'api/products?schema=synopsis'));
$opt = array('resource' => 'products');
$opt['id'] = 8;
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
$resources = $xml->children()->children();
$resources->quantity = 100;
$opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->edit($opt);
```